# VoiceOver Doesn't Read Colon on iPhone

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, accessibility, voiceover

I use a third-party website to get the public ipv6. When I use VoiceOver to read the IPV6 address, it omits the colon in the address. But it reads the dot in the IPV4 address. Is there a way to read the colon in the IPV6 address?

Comment: This doesn't seem like a programming problem, unless you mean that some code you've written uses VoiceOver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your verbosity setting.

Settings > Accessibility > VoiceOver > Verbosity > Punctuation

Set it to "All".

[image]

If you look at "All", you'll see the colon listed (about halfway down the list).

The default is "Some", which does not include the colon.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to read the colon in the IPV6 address?

The solution suggested by [@Slugolicious](https://stackoverflow.com/users/76714/slugolicious) is perfectly correct  but, as there aren't any [notifications](https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/en/mobile/ios/development/#accessibility-options) to be informed of this setting value *(see the `Recap` section in the link )*, you should imagine the user has already made this modification on his own for an appropriate reading out by VoiceOver.

To reach this goal through programming in Swift *(iOS)*, I recommend to use the following attributes:

- [accessibilitySpeechPunctuation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsattributedstring/key/1620201-accessibilityspeechpunctuation) for an IPV4 address.
- [accessibilitySpeechSpellOut](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsattributedstring/key/3333285-accessibilityspeechspellout) for an IPV6 address due to the letters that may be inside the numbers between the colons.

A basic example with two labels highlights these notions through the following code:

```
  class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var ipv4: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var ipv6: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    
        let myTxtIpv4 = "177.255.255.255"
        let strV4 = NSAttributedString(string: myTxtIpv4,
                                       attributes: [.accessibilitySpeechPunctuation: true ])
        ipv4.accessibilityAttributedLabel = strV4
    
        let myTxtIpv6 = "2001:0db8:85a3:8a2e:0000:7334"
        let strV6 = NSAttributedString(string: myTxtIpv6,
                                       attributes: [.accessibilitySpeechSpellOut: true ])
        ipv6.accessibilityAttributedLabel = strV6
    }


  }
```

Following this rationale, **VoiceOver will read colons of your IPV6 addresses on iPhone**.

Comment: That's a great solution if you're trying to have special characters read in an app that you are developing.  I wasn't familiar with those two traits.  Thanks for posting.  However, it sounds like the OP was getting the IPV6 from a third party app, which they don't have control over, but still wanted to hear the punctuation. I think the only solution then is to change your VoiceOver verbosity setting.

Comment: @slugolicious You're right but the question wasn't accurate enough to me  (info with a third-party app including some 'swift' and 'ios' tags), that's why I deemed it important to clarify the dev' face of the problem for those who could be interested in this perspective (regarding the 'swift' and 'ios' tags) . I think your way was the appropriate one to answer the initial question. 

Comment: Makes sense given the dev tags on the question.